# When to resolve aliases while parsing?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, tokenize

When parsing (ANTLR4 in Java) when should I resolve aliases?

I have a simple "bash" looking DSL (commands connected with pipes), something like `command1 | command2 | ...` with a predefined set of commands. I want to give the user an option to define custom aliases like `alias com='command2 | command3'` (bash style). Then the user should be able to use it in a query `command1 | com` which would be equivalent to `command1 | command2 | command3`.

Should I do it (alias resolution):

1. on the raw input text supplied by the user. I.e. change the string `command1 | com` into `command1 | command2 | command3` before lexing/parsing,
2. after I get the tokens from lexing,
3. while building the parse tree,
4. or when I traverse it (execute the commands)?

1) seems not a good way since I don't know anything about the incoming string and replacing aliases would be a nightmare. 2) might be no easier. I think I remember that 3) isn't a good approach altogether, but my memory might be just playing tricks on me. This would lead me to my initial guess - option number 4). Am I correct on this or am I missing something? My only concern here is that the alias can be a small query on its own so I would have to also parse that during alias resolution, but that should be doable?

Comment: @EJP as in the example I have a set of predefined commands (like in bash) and I want to give the user an option to alias a set of them to some other "name". So basically exactly like an alias in bash where you can do `alias ...='cd ../..'`. When I have no aliases I just parse this and execute commands sequentially. With aliases I have to resolve them first but I am not sure at which stage?

Comment: I'd go with 4 or even later - depending on whether by "traversal" you mean actually executing your language. Aliases, and generally what a given piece of code eventually *does* seems like a semantical feature of your language, not its syntax. I'd make a pass through the AST to gather the aliases in a table (assuming they have global scope), then use that table to resolve them while interpreting the script.

Comment: 3 is doable, and in fact it's traditionally how C compilers work. (Or at least used to.) They're supposed to be single-pass, this is also why you have to declare a function before using it in C. That said, vaguely remembering my compilers class assignment, it was kind of bothersome to keep the (in my case) variable scope around everywhere it was needed *during* the parsing. ANTLR might make this easier but it's still easiest to just walk the AST or part of it when it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your file would have both the definitions and uses of the aliases:

```
alias com='command2 | command3' 
command1 | com                     # expands to command1 | command2 | command3
```

which makes me think options 1) and 2) would both be difficult/impossible because you need to parse the file to determine:

- an alias' definition
- where the alias is used

I think option 3) would work, but would result in code that's relatively hard to maintain, because it wouldn't employ separation of concerns.  That's why, in my own projects, I typically apply something like option 4) -- first build some kind of parse tree, then in a later pass (or passes) resolve the aliases.

Of course, it's impossible to say for sure without knowing the full details of your language and/or grammar.

Comment: thanks Matt! Yeah I will be storing the aliases somewhere (probably DB) and the user will input the query, yes. Indeed 1/2 seem very unfeasible, 3 not being better. The only concern with 4 I have is that an alias can be by itself a smaller query which I also have to parse and add somehow to the original structure but I am not going to support aliases inside aliases so that shouldn't be that hard!